# Duplicate package names ending with ".overlay"

Tags: system-apps, overlay

I'm using Vodafone Smart ultra 7. I observed that every system package has a duplicate which is the `package.name` and `package.name.overlay`

- `com.android.systemui` - `com.android.systemui.overlay`
- `com.android.musicfx` - `com.android.musicfx.overlay`
- `com.android.dreams.basic` - `com.android.dreams.basic.overlay`

Literally every system package has duplicate copy.

That prohibits me from using lock task.

What are these packages?

Comment: Do you use (or does the OS have) any overlay theming service? One example is RRO/Substratum.

Comment: How could I check it ? I haven't Installed any custom OS or rooted my device !!It is out of the box device.